# Maven não faz download das bibliotecas

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Estou utilizando o IntelliJ e o plugin para Maven (primeira vez), estou tentando fazer funcionar para que faça o download das bibliotecas que utilizo no meu projeto, porém ele não está fazendo o download.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>src.main.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>IR-IndexadorRepositorio</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
                <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Log:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building IR-IndexadorRepositorio 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ IR-IndexadorRepositorio ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (windows-1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ IR-IndexadorRepositorio ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding windows-1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 8 source files to D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[3,23] error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[4,33] error: package org.apache.lucene.analysis does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[5,42] error: package org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[6,33] error: package org.apache.lucene.document does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[7,30] error: package org.apache.lucene.index does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[8,30] error: package org.apache.lucene.index does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[9,44] error: package org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[10,31] error: package org.apache.lucene.search does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[11,31] error: package org.apache.lucene.search does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[12,31] error: package org.apache.lucene.search does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[13,31] error: package org.apache.lucene.search does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[14,30] error: package org.apache.lucene.store does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[15,30] error: package org.apache.lucene.store does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[16,29] error: package org.apache.lucene.util does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[22,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Logger
  location: class Buscador
D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[1,23] error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[2,33] error: package org.apache.lucene.analysis does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[3,42] error: package org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[4,33] error: package org.apache.lucene.document does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[5,33] error: package org.apache.lucene.document does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[6,33] error: package org.apache.lucene.document does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[7,30] error: package org.apache.lucene.index does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[8,30] error: package org.apache.lucene.index does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[9,30] error: package org.apache.lucene.store does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[10,30] error: package org.apache.lucene.store does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[11,29] error: package org.apache.lucene.util does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[12,22] error: package org.apache.tika does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[21,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Logger
  location: class Indexador
D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[23,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class IndexWriter
  location: class Indexador
D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[25,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Tika
  location: class Indexador
D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[139,4] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Tika
  location: class Indexador
D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[146,4] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class IndexWriter
  location: class Indexador
D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[21,0] error: duplicate class: br.com.ir.Buscador
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Princ.java:[317,20] error: cannot access Buscador
[INFO] 34 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.133 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-04-10T16:12:30-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/22M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project IR-IndexadorRepositorio: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[3,23] error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[4,33] error: package org.apache.lucene.analysis does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[5,42] error: package org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[6,33] error: package org.apache.lucene.document does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[7,30] error: package org.apache.lucene.index does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[8,30] error: package org.apache.lucene.index does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[9,44] error: package org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[10,31] error: package org.apache.lucene.search does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[11,31] error: package org.apache.lucene.search does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[12,31] error: package org.apache.lucene.search does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[13,31] error: package org.apache.lucene.search does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[14,30] error: package org.apache.lucene.store does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[15,30] error: package org.apache.lucene.store does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[16,29] error: package org.apache.lucene.util does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[22,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR] location: class Buscador
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[1,23] error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[2,33] error: package org.apache.lucene.analysis does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[3,42] error: package org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[4,33] error: package org.apache.lucene.document does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[5,33] error: package org.apache.lucene.document does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[6,33] error: package org.apache.lucene.document does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[7,30] error: package org.apache.lucene.index does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[8,30] error: package org.apache.lucene.index does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[9,30] error: package org.apache.lucene.store does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[10,30] error: package org.apache.lucene.store does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[11,29] error: package org.apache.lucene.util does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[12,22] error: package org.apache.tika does not exist
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[21,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR] location: class Indexador
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[23,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class IndexWriter
[ERROR] location: class Indexador
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[25,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Tika
[ERROR] location: class Indexador
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[139,4] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Tika
[ERROR] location: class Indexador
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Indexador.java:[146,4] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class IndexWriter
[ERROR] location: class Indexador
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Buscador.java:[21,0] error: duplicate class: br.com.ir.Buscador
[ERROR] D:\Workspace\Desk\IR-IndexadorRepositorio\src\main\java\Princ.java:[317,20] error: cannot access Buscador
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Você progrediu desde que postou sua pergunta? Poderia nos dizer em que pé que está? Talvez esse tutorial pode te ajudar: http://www.javacreed.com/how-to-use-maven-with-an-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema não está no `Maven` ou no `IntelliJ` e sim no código do `pom.xml`, eu estava incluindo as `<dependencies>` dentro do `<dependencyManagement>`. Bastou retirar o `<dependencyManagement>` que tudo funcionou perfeitamente.

Segue o código como ficou:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>IRMaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
                <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</project>
```